# JTwitter plugin returns 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, twitter

Strange problem because plugin worked very well but from some point just stoped to work.
Now returns 404 error. It looks like the twitter  id is wrong now.

Plugin on this page

```
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jtwitter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin appears to be from 2009, I am guessing that it probably has not been updated to work with the latest revisions to the Twitter API. I would find a different solution.

Do you need this for a specific CMS or platform?

Comment: I used this on one not too old project (about 1 year ago). Yes it is n2 cms. Probably best solution is to use different plugin and to implement that part of website again. Thanks mate.